# QListView custom display

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010

I have a QListView with a Custom Display based on a simple contacts list. All the fields EXCEPT the email address field render just fine, and the items on the page otherwise look exactly as formatted. There is definitely data in the field, but this one simple text field isn't rendering as a mailto link in the QListView. The href code is correct, it works when tested in a simple html file, but not on the Sharepoint page.

Viewing source, all I see for the email code is literally `mailto:<%EmailAddress%>` where it should show `mailto:myname@mydomain.com` as it appears on the list. What's REALLY strange is that I tested the <%EmailAddress%> token on the custom display as just another field, no href code, but it doesn't show on screen that way either, which is even odder.

Here's the current code as an email link:

```
<a href="mailto:<%EmailAddress%>"><%First_Name%> <%Last_Name%></a> Ext. <%Extension%><br>
<%Job_Title%><br><br>
```

Is there something funky about using an email field/code in Custom Displays? Using the generic show fields tab, it shows up uneventfully. Something else? Or can you not use "live" tags in the display at all? But then why didn't it show up as a text field? I was under the impression that you could use pretty much any simple html code in the custom displays. No?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, this is on Sharepoint 2010 and I believe version 6.5 of QuickApps.

Answer (score 1):

I figgered it out. Turns out the field names are <%CaSe Sensitive%>. Who knew? Works like a champ now. Is that documented anywhere, btw? Just wondering.